# How to handle NSExtensionActivationRule is truepredicate?

Tags: ios, swift

I got warning:
Embedded binary's NSExtensionActivationRule is TRUEPREDICATE. Before you submit your containing app to the App Store, be sure to replace all uses of TRUEPREDICATE with specific predicate statements or NSExtensionActivationRule keys. If any extensions in your containing app include TRUEPREDICATE, the app will be rejected

what can I do? I try to modify NSExtension, but I really don't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to specify every data type you want to use in Info.plist of your App Extension.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) for the available keys. Look for `NSExtensionActivationRule`.

[image: Here is a example:]

//UPDATE:

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
```

Comment: The link above appears to be broken:

Here is the working [documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Artaicles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Your link is broken as well, it was only a temporary link ;) But I corrected it!

Comment: For detail query refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546283/ios-share-extension-how-to-support-wav-files

Comment: Also use this one for sharing File and Audio
<></>
<></>

Answer (score 3):

I wanted my app to accept **text only**. This is what works:

```
...
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationUsesStrictMatching</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
...
```